# Python list comprehension for list of dictd into a list of tuple with a subset of dict key-value pairs

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to use list comprehensions to covert the above into a list of tuples but with only a subset of each dictionary in the tuple.

SOURCE

```
source = [
  {'gem': 'gold', 'dimensions': {"weight":120, "height":0, "color":240}, 'shine': '90', 'worth': 10000}, 
  {'gem': 'diamond', 'dimensions': {"weight":80, "height":20, "color":10}, 'shine': '190', 'worth': 5000}
  ...
]
```

From the source above, the list should look like this once completed:

```
[(120, 240),(80, 10) ]
```

Each tuple in the list is based on the the dict at the matching index in Source but only parts of a nested dict are selected for inclusion in the type:

Desired Dataset

```
[(dimensions.weight, dimensions.color), ...]
```

I've tried several different things but cannot get further than this:

```
[g["dimensions"] for g in source]
```

which yields

```
[{"weight":120, "height":0, "color":240}, {"weight":80, "height":20, "color":10}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close, just need to specify the values you want to include in the tuple

```
[(g["dimensions"]["weight"], g["dimensions"]["color"]) for g in source]
```

Comment: Sure no problem :)